# FPDF submit form to PDF issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, fpdf

I'm trying to use one of the FPDF examples scripts and re-purpose it. The current script will submit what is in the "textarea" to a PDF. I would like it to submit the whole page to PDF, if I created more elements etc.  It looks like its looking for the name 'text' so I named like the whole form 'text', divs etc and it does not work unless its a text field or area.

The 'html2pdf.php' as far as I know has no reference to just allowing text boxes.

I am assuming its this part here that is the cause, but I cant figure out how to rework it to convert a whole form set to PDF. Ultimately I am trying to use this for lots of inputs (name, address, etc)

```
<?php
require('html2pdf.php');

if(isset($_POST['text']))
{    
$pdf=new PDF_HTML();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
$pdf->AddPage();
$text=$_POST['text'];
if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')=='1')
    $text=stripslashes($text);
$pdf->WriteHTML($text);
$pdf->Output();
exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML2PDF</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" target="_blank">
Content:<br>
<textarea name="text" cols="80" rows="15">test</textarea><br>
<input type="submit" name="html" value="Generate PDF">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:  Let me add some images to help illustrate my issues. I know I have a hard time explaining things.

In image 1 it shows the standard code I posted above, notice the red marker. This is all that is generated to PDF, I would like to make a whole page be generated, not just input and text fields.
http://vslan.net/up/1.png

Example, look at image 2. Notice again the red marker, this is just text within the form/body that I want to be generated into the PDF (it is currently not on the working one either).  The green is the whole test code I am trying to get.
http://vslan.net/up/2.png

If some one could help me re-code the above to allow this that would be grateful.

Comment: fpdf couldn't care less how many/few fields you have in your form, or what types they are. It's just dealing with text. `$pdf->WriteHTML('foobarbaz')` and `$pdf->WriteHTML($_POST['field_that_contains_foobarbaz'])` are both identical as far as fpdf is concerned

Comment: how would i make $pdf->WriteHTML('whatever') write all the contents of a form. so far i've only got it to write one element. and what if i dont want it to be an element but just some random text on the page?

Comment: call it multiple times. it's not fpdf's job to try and guess WHAT you want printed in the pdf. you have to tell it. if you want 5 form fields printed, then call writehtml() 5 times

Comment: Oh ok, so i have to keep calling it. I thought i was supposed to put it all into one writehtml()

Comment: you can do that too. what you write out is up to you. `$foo = $a . $b; $fpdf->writehtml($foo)` would be mostly be the same as `$fpdf->writehtml($a); $fpdf->writehtml($b)`

Comment: so am i putting all my html in a $test1 = "<b>test</b>"; ? or can I not keep it written out like it is above? thats what im confused about.

Comment: Marc B, I made an edit to the post, not sure if you could help me that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
if(isset($_POST['text']))
{
    $pdf=new PDF_HTML();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',12);
    $pdf->AddPage();
    foreach($_POST['text'] as $text)
    {
        if(ini_get('magic_quotes_gpc')=='1')
            $text=stripslashes($text);
        $pdf->WriteHTML($text);
    }
    $pdf->Output();
    exit;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML2PDF</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" target="_blank">
            Content:<br>
            Text 1:<input type="text" name="text[]"></br>
            Text 2:<input type="text" name="text[]"></br>
            Text 3:<input type="text" name="text[]"></br>
            Text 4:<input type="text" name="text[]"></br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
?>
```